# Выбор неизвестного максимального значения в таблице PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE company(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE person(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    company_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Есть компании и у компаний есть сотрудники, мне надо одним запросом выбрать компанию с максимальным количеством сотрудников(Название компании и количество сотрудников). Количество сотрудников в каждой конкретной компании так-же как и общее их количество не известно.

Подвох который ставит меня в тупик это то что нужно сделать это одним запросом.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM company c, person p
WHERE c.id = p.company_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Если у нескольких компаний одинаковое, причём максимальное, количество сотрудников - будет выведена случайная из них.

Если же нужна не одна, а все, то чуть сложнее. Например, так:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM company c, person p
WHERE c.id = p.company_id
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(pp.*) 
                   FROM person pp
                   GROUP BY pp.company_id
                   ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1
                  )
```

Comment: 1. а так что-бы обе вернулись нельзя сделать? 2. А что значит COUNT(*) cnt ну понятно что счетчик но как вы указали что мы ищем его большее значение а не меньшее на пример? 3.ORDER BY 2 что значит в этом контексте? Спасибо, извините что так много вопросов.

Comment: @Павел `ORDER BY 2` - это сортировка по второму столбцу в результате. В данном случае - по `cnt` (он же `COUNT(*)`). Так как сортировка идёт по убыванию (`DESC`) и берётся только первая строка (`LIMIT 1`), то в результат попадает только макс. значение.

Comment: @Regent `DESC` - я правильно понял что это и есть указание на то что мы сортируем по убыванию? А зачем написано `GROUP BY c.name` почему не достаточно `SELECT c.name,` зачем еще дополнительно группировать?

Comment: Не группируя, невозможно посчитать количество. Ведь количество считается по группе.

Comment: @Павел да, `DESC` (от слова _descending_) - это по убыванию. Насчет `GROUP BY` - потому что надо посчитать количество строк для каждого `name` по отдельности, а для этого нужно сгруппировать записи по `name` (чтобы записи с одинаковым `name` были в одной группе) и посчитать количество записей в каждой группе (с помощью `COUNT`). В итоге получим количество (сотрудников) для каждого `name` (компании).